# Value of global array variable changes when local array variable is changed in js

Tags: javascript

I am assigning the value of a global variable `globalValue` to  a local array `localArray`. On changing the value of `localArray` , `globalValue` is also changed. why does that happen and how do i fix it?

```
    var globalValue=[];

    globalValue['firstIndex']=1;
    globalValue['secondIndex']=2;
    globalValue['thirdIndex']=3;
    globalValue['checkIndex']="CHECK";

function checkGlobalChange()
{
    var localArray=globalValue;

    localArray['checkIndex']="CHECKCHANGE";

    return true;
}

function callCheckFuction()
{
    alert("Global Array checkIndex Value Before Call : "+globalValue['checkIndex']);
    if(checkGlobalChange())
    {
        alert("Global Array checkIndex Value After Call : "+globalValue['checkIndex']);
    }
}

<html>
     <body>
        <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="callCheckFuction()">
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should also be aware that there are (strictly speaking) no associative arrays in JS and what you have there is an `object`. It should be defined like this: `var globalValue = {};`

Answer (score 5):

You have two variables pointing towards **one** array.

To have different arrays, you must clone the first one. This is usually done using the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function :

```
var localArray=globalValue.slice();
```

But `slice` would only copy the int indexed properties (the properties you normally use on an array). What you want is a deep (or not deep) cloning function. A simple search for "javascript deep clone" would give you such a function if you need it.